# Name conflict in Excel but no actual conflict

Tags: excel, vba

All of a sudden I started getting this error when I started entering data into the `Chair_Orders` table...

> The name "Chair_Orders" already exists. Click Yes to use that version of the name, or click No to rename the version of "Chair_Orders" you're moving or copying.

If I go to the Name Manager there is no conflict.

I tried going to the table itself using the Table Tools and renaming the table to `Chair_Orders2` and I now get no conflict but if I try and change it back, I get an error saying that `Chair_Orders` already exists and it must be unique.

I have a bunch of VBA that refers to `Chair_Orders`so I really need to change it back. Is there any way to find the conflict?

Here is my code...

```
Sub Print_Worksheet()

'Set Paper Size
Worksheets("Chair Orders").PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLetter

'Clear defined print area
Worksheets("Chair Orders").PageSetup.PrintArea = ""

'Remove all filters
Worksheets("Chair Orders").ListObjects("Chair_Orders").AutoFilter.ShowAllData

'Filter out upholstered orders
'Worksheets("Chair Orders").ListObjects("Chair_Orders").Range.AutoFilter Field:=14, _
        Criteria1:="="

'Filter out Shipped Items - Not everything gets upholstered... Old inventory etc.
Worksheets("Chair Orders").ListObjects("Chair_Orders").Range.AutoFilter Field:=17, _
        Criteria1:="="

'Sort by Must Ship Date
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Chair_Orders")
Dim sortcolumn As Range
Set sortcolumn = Range("Chair_Orders[Must Ship By]")
With tbl.Sort
   .SortFields.Clear
   .SortFields.Add Key:=sortcolumn, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
   .Header = xlYes
   .Apply
End With


'Hide cells we don't want to print
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("I:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("Q:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

'Setup page to print fit
'With Worksheets("Chair Orders").PageSetup
' .Zoom = False
' .FitToPagesTall = 1
' .FitToPagesWide = 1
'End With
With Worksheets("Chair Orders").PageSetup
 .Zoom = 46
End With

'Remove shading from printouts
Worksheets("Chair Orders").PageSetup.BlackAndWhite = True

'Print the worksheet
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=2, Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False


'Show the hidden cells again
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("A:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

Call Reset_Filters

End Sub
Sub View_Schedule()

Call Reset_Filters

'Sort by Must Ship Date
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Chair_Orders")
Dim sortcolumn As Range
Set sortcolumn = Range("Chair_Orders[Must Ship By]")
With tbl.Sort
   .SortFields.Clear
   .SortFields.Add Key:=sortcolumn, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
   .Header = xlYes
   .Apply
End With



'Unhide all columns
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("A:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
'Hide cells we don't want to print
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("G:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("L:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("V:X").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("AG:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
Sub View_EOD()

Call Reset_Filters

'Sort by Must Ship Date
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Chair_Orders")
Dim sortcolumn As Range
Set sortcolumn = Range("Chair_Orders[Sales Order]")
With tbl.Sort
   .SortFields.Clear
   .SortFields.Add Key:=sortcolumn, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
   .Header = xlYes
   .Apply
End With



'Unhide all columns
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("A:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
'Hide cells we don't want to print
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("A:B").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("F:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("P:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
Sub Update_Invoice()

Call Reset_Filters

'Sort by Must Ship Date
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Chair_Orders")
Dim sortcolumn As Range
Set sortcolumn = Range("Chair_Orders[Sales Order]")
With tbl.Sort
   .SortFields.Clear
   .SortFields.Add Key:=sortcolumn, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
   .Header = xlYes
   .Apply
End With



'Unhide all columns
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("A:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
'Hide cells we don't want to print
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("A:B").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("F:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("S:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
Sub Print_Schedule()

'Set Paper Size
Worksheets("Chair Orders").PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLetter

'Clear defined print area
Worksheets("Chair Orders").PageSetup.PrintArea = ""

'Remove all filters
Worksheets("Chair Orders").ListObjects("Chair_Orders").AutoFilter.ShowAllData

'Filter out upholstered orders
'Worksheets("Chair Orders").ListObjects("Chair_Orders").Range.AutoFilter Field:=14, _
        Criteria1:="="

'Filter out Shipped Items - Not everything gets upholstered... Old inventory etc.
Worksheets("Chair Orders").ListObjects("Chair_Orders").Range.AutoFilter Field:=17, _
        Criteria1:="="

'Sort by Must Ship By Date then UPH Date
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Chair Orders").ListObjects("Chair_Orders").Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Chair Orders").ListObjects("Chair_Orders").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Chair_Orders[Must Ship By]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Chair Orders").ListObjects("Chair_Orders").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Chair_Orders[UPH DATE]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues _
        , Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Chair Orders").ListObjects("Chair_Orders").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Chair_Orders[UPHOLSTERER]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues _
        , Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Chair Orders").ListObjects("Chair_Orders").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

'Sort by Must Ship By Date
'Dim ws As Worksheet
'Set ws = ActiveSheet
'Dim tbl As ListObject
'Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Chair_Orders")
'Dim sortcolumn As Range
'Set sortcolumn = Range("Chair_Orders[Must Ship By]")
'With tbl.Sort
'   .SortFields.Clear
'   .SortFields.Add Key:=sortcolumn, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
'   .Header = xlYes
'   .Apply
'End With


'Unhide all columns
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("A:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
'Hide cells we don't want to print
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("G:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("V:X").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("AG:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

'Setup page to print fit
'With Worksheets("Chair Orders").PageSetup
' .Zoom = False
' .FitToPagesTall = 1
' .FitToPagesWide = 1
'End With
With Worksheets("Chair Orders").PageSetup
 .Zoom = 46
End With

'Remove shading from printouts
Worksheets("Chair Orders").PageSetup.BlackAndWhite = True

'Print the worksheet
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=2, Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False


'Show the hidden cells again
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("A:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

Call Reset_Filters

End Sub

Sub Reset_Filters()

'Set formatting
Call Copy_Formatting


'Unhide all columns
Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("A:BZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

'Remove all filters
Worksheets("Chair Orders").ListObjects("Chair_Orders").AutoFilter.ShowAllData

'Filter out Invoiced Items
Worksheets("Chair Orders").ListObjects("Chair_Orders").Range.AutoFilter Field:=18, _
        Criteria1:="="

'Sort by Must Ship Date
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Chair_Orders")
Dim sortcolumn As Range
Set sortcolumn = Range("Chair_Orders[Must Ship By]")
With tbl.Sort
   .SortFields.Clear
   .SortFields.Add Key:=sortcolumn, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
   .Header = xlYes
   .Apply
End With



End Sub


Sub Copy_Formatting()
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Remove all filters
    Worksheets("Chair Orders").ListObjects("Chair_Orders").AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    'Copy formatting from the first row
    Range("A11:AF11").Select
    Selection.Copy

    'Paste Formatting
    Range("Chair_Orders[[DATE]:[QCER]]").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub

Sub Save_and_Close()

    Call Reset_Filters

    Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("A1").Select

    'Close the extra window if it is open
    On Error Resume Next
    Windows("Production Planner.xlsm:2").Close
    On Error GoTo 0

    Worksheets("Chair Orders").Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: If this is a VBA question, please show the code that is causing the problem

Comment: As far as I know there are no VBA issues... I'll add my code

Comment: There was an Excel VBA Editor add-in several years back that had a feature to "clean" all the VBA code. What it basically did was to export all the modules to text files (.bas, ...), delete all those modules, then import them back in cleanly. This was apparently to clean up the symbol tables IIRC. This may be a case where you could perform the same operation and have success.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteExcel4Macro "SUM(DELETE.NAME(NAMES()))"`